# SSRS to make table appear below on same page when exceeding PDF page width

Tags: sql-server, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report that contains a table. The users will enter a project number and this table will display a value for each year the project number has been around for. The table will grow in columns depending on how many years are associated with that project number.

Typically a project will only have a life span of 3 - 5 years, which will fit nicely when exported to a PDF. However there are a few rare occasions where a project will exceed this life span, causing the table to grow greatly in column numbers. Causing the table to appear on multiple pages when exported to a PDF.

The issue here is that because there are some other tables below this table, their information is displayed before the remainder of the original table will be displayed.

My question is, is it possible for the remainder of the original table to appear below itself, before the rest of the report is displayed?

Some solutions I have come across that I would like to avoid are -

1. add a page break after the original table so that the remainder will appear on a new page before returning any information from the tables below - **Reason for avoiding** - due to the nature of the report returning different amounts of data depending on which project number is entered, this has the ability to create a lot of empty space in the report.
2. export the report to excel instead - **Reason for avoiding** - this is not something my client whishes to explore
3. changing the table so that each year is a new row instead of column **Reason for avoiding** - There is other data being displayed in the original table that I have omitted from this question in order to simplify my question. This 'other data' is the reason why the years are placed into columns rather than rows.

Thanks in advance

**My Current Work Around - Update 20 July 17**

I have adjusted the layout of the report and added a page break before and after this table. This has allowed the remainder of the table to appear on a new page before any other information is displayed. Though I did state I wanted to avoid this option, by adjusting the layout of the report I have minimized the amount of empty space that appears on the report (I would like to note that there is still empty space, however it isn't noticeable on about 95% of the tested reports, unless you really go looking for it)

Comment: You can split your wide table in some narrower tables, for example, if I know  the "normal" size is for 5 years and I can have maximum 15 years, I'll put 3 tables one under another and calculate a hidden parameter n = number of years to display. Then split the data to display using NTILE function in the dataset and hide the second and the third table if the hidden parameter <= 5 for second table and <=10 for the 3d table

Comment: @sepupic Thank you for the information. I am unsure of the maximum amount of years, as projects can be adopted from other companies at any time and their current lifespan will not be known until they have been adopted. Also one project could have multiple entries for one year (though the majority only have one entry), due to the report reflecting certain changes in that year. I guess one option I could try to implement here would be to greatly over estimate the possible maximum amount of years. However this maybe only a temporary fix. Thanks again